# Removing large files from branch commit history using BFG Repo Cleaner

Tags: git, bfg-repo-cleaner

I made a pull request on a repository and unfortunately, my branch contained some large files which are now present in my branch's commit history. To address this, I decided to use BFG Repo Cleaner.

However, I'm unsure about the correct next steps,since I did not exactly followed the steps that are specified on the BFG page, i.e. I did use the clone mirror command, but simply utilized the command

`git-bfg --delete-files <file-to-delete>`,

and it seems that the files have been removed from my local repositories history .My question is: Can I simply push my local changes now, and will the large files be gone from the commit history on the remote repository? I want to ensure that my pull request remains clean without those large files and I do not change any of the other commits from the repo.